# How can I find $\int{\sqrt{\left(b^2-1\right)x^2+1\over-x^2+1}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, conic-sections

I got this from the perimeter of an ellipse.  I came up with the formula: arclength of f(x) for x from a to b=$\int_a^b\sqrt{f'(x)^2+1}dx$.  Since an ellipse has the equation: $$\left({x-h\over a}\right)^2+\left({y-k\over b}\right)2=1$$
The arclength can be found to be:
$$\int_{-b}^b\sqrt{\left(b\sqrt{1-\left(x-h\over a\right)^2}+k\right)^2+1}$$
Which, if you let h and k equal 0 and a equal 1, is the problem in the title.  But how do I proceed from here.

Comment: Do you know how to do this for the case of the unit circle, and then the generalized equation of a circle? An ellipse is just a stretched version of a circle, so a contraction substation will work easily.

Comment: Well, for the unit circle b becomes 1 and the problem is S(1/sqrt(1-x^2))dx.  The integral then is arcsin(x).  But if I scale this (which is what I assume you mean by "contraction substation"), it's just the perimeter of a bigger circle.  So I don't see how to use that.  I know it would work for the area though.

Comment: Sorry, I meant substitution. Do the substitution $u = \frac{b(x-h)}{a}$, what do you get? The contraction factor is $\frac{b}{a}$, and the translation (of the center) results in the h, k terms.